# How to fix " State Error (active) E0513 a value of type “const wchar_t *” cannot be assigned to an entity of type “wchar_t *”"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to change the properties of a file using C ++
what am I doing wrong ?
The code is completely taken

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/stg/writeread-sample

```
propspec.ulKind = PRSPEC_LPWSTR;
propspec.lpwstr = L"Property Name";// this line problem

propvarWrite.vt = VT_LPWSTR;
propvarWrite.pwszVal = L"Property Value"; // this line problem
```

Comment: 1，If you're certain that the other code won't write into it, you can cast the constness away with const_cast<wchar_t *>。
2，You could make a writable duplicate of the string with something like _wcsdup, you should also not forget to deallocate it later.
3，You could store the string in a wchar_t array in global or static scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message tells already: String literals are of type `const char[]` or `const wchar_t[]` (depending on underlying type), and you cannot legally assign an array of const to a pointer to non-const (some compilers accept such code, though, just emitting a warning), solely the other way round is allowed.

Question is now, how to get out of that dilemma?

*In general:*

If you are **100%** sure (really, not the very least doubt!) that the strings won't get modified, you could just cast the const away:

```
wchar_t* ptr = const_cast<wchar_t*>(L"...");
```

If you have the **least doubt** about (modifications of string literals are undefined behaviour!), then copy the literal into an array:

```
wchar_t value[] = L"...";
ptr = value;
```

At this point, you need to be sure that the called function won't take ownership of the string, though: Would it try to free the string? Would it store the pointer somewhere for later usage, such that the array pointed to must live longer than the scope of the calling function?

If so, you might need to use a global array or `malloc` memory to copy the string to...

*In specific case:*

If you peek into the documentation of [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propidl/nf-propidl-ipropertystorage-readmultiple) and [write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propidl/nf-propidl-ipropertystorage-writemultiple) functions, you see that the structs in question are passed to `const` parameters. Well, actually, that will make the *pointer* constant, not the data pointed to, still it looks pretty much safe to assume that the strings won't get modified (if need be, copied to somewhere – well, written to some file), so you actually should be fine with the `const_cast` option.

Side note: The example doesn't free the strings read back again; pretty interesting now the question for ownership (who will free them again)? Unfortunately, the documentation is not precise about...